# Using classes to observe a page

Tags: javascript, observer-pattern

I am writing a script that needs to detect elements **added** to a Web page, for example events rendered in a calendar (div tags). I don't care about elements that are removed. There should be at most 20-30 such elements on the page.

My idea - short and easy code - is to use a specific class ("myName") to brand elements already in the page. At regular intervals I would poll the page:

```
// Get all divs in the calendar: 
var allDivsCount=myCalendar.querySelectorAll("div").length;
// Get already branded divs
var oldDivsCount=myCalendar.querySelectorAll("div.myName").length;
if (allDivsCount > oldDivsCount) {
    // brand the new divs and do stuff
}
```

Is this a good practice, or is there a better way to do it? Are there libraries that already have such logic implemented?

I am trying to avoid DOMNodeInserted as some browsers don't support it and it is deprecated (due to performance issues, from what I've read).

Comment: I know you don't care about elements that are removed, but you will get the same count if an element is removed _then_ a new one added, looking like nothing has changed...

Comment: I'd reccomend glasses over classes when observing webpages. A small simple interval polling that does'nt run to often is'nt really a problem, it's when you constantly poll something, or stick to much mumbojumbo in the function that you get into trouble.

Comment: @Ian no, oldDivsCount will have changed

Comment: @adeneo I'd love to see a solution that doesn't involve constant poll, that's one of the purposes of my question. In my scenario the poll has to happen as long as the user is on the page.

Comment: `DOMNodeInserted` have worked for me in the past but a bit quirky depending on the browser that you are supporting. Do you know exactly what triggers for the `DOM` to change? If you know exactly the elements that triggers it then maybe you should watch out for this instead of watching for the `DOM` changes itself. Just a thought.

Comment: @DennisRongo I don't, there might be multiple reasons (new event from server, event added by the user, user switching to another month, interactive filters...)

Comment: What is adding the elements to the page? A library you don't control? Your own code?

Comment: @Ian several scripts I don't control. The changes can be pushed by the server or triggered by the user (and the calendar is just one example). I am in an observer position.

Comment: @Christophe, I've seen tons of scenarios like this which is why I've looked into a solution before. If you need to make it work across all browsers, seems like a loop might be your only solution (http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/).

Comment: @Christophe I just wanted to make sure it wasn't like you could tap into an API's callbacks and find out when certain things are completed, and obviously could be easy that way. I'm sure you had thought of that, but wanted to see

Comment: @Christophe, you're in an odd situation where you're not in control of the `DOM` manipulation. Client-side events such as date changes and server-side calls can easily be intercepted if you have total control of the app. Long polling might be your only option OR intercept events as they occur.

Comment: @DennisRongo could you elaborate on watch, maybe post as an answer? I've heard about it, but the purpose is to observe object properties so I am not sure how it relates to my current issue (observe **added** elements).

Answer (score 0):

I know that you're against `DOMNodeInserted` but I'll added it anyways for options (in case you're not supporting older version of IE).

I blogged about this a while [back](http://menacestudio.com/jquery-attach-events-to-dynamic-elements-added-via-ajax) but it seems like the same solution still applies today (but like I said, depending on the browsers you currently support).

**Example:**

```
$(document.body).on('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.toString() === 'HTMLBodyElement') {
       console.log(e);
    }
});
```

This triggers any changes within the `body` not just the `body` itself.

```
$('#context').append($('<div />')); // triggers the event above
```

If you can intercept a `DOM` change (an AJAX call for instance) and create a global callback function, that would be ideal instead of the `setInterval` option.

```
var globalCallback = function() { 
    /** Do something when the DOM changes */ 
};

/** Global AJAX event to watch for all AJAX complete within the body */
$('body').ajaxComplete(globalCallback);
```

This is just one example (AJAX callbacks) of course.

Comment: Just as a note, since jQuery 1.9, they recommend using `document` for attaching AJAX events: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document